# POST json returns 400 with curl but functional test working

Tags: php, json, symfony, post, curl

I am trying to build the POST of an API using Symfony2 and FOSRestBundle. The following functional test returns OK.

```
 public function testPostArticleAction(){

        $this->client->request(
                'POST',
                '/api/v1/articles.json',
                array(),
                array(),
                array('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'),
                '{"articleContent":"The content of the content"}'
                );
        $response = $this->client->getResponse();

        $this->assertJsonResponse($response,201, false); 
    }
```

But when I try to send a request via Curl with the same request body, it gives me a 400 invalid json message:

> {"code":400,"message":"Invalid json message received"}

Here are the curl commands I have tried:

> curl -X POST -d '{"articleContent":"title1"}'
>   http://localhost:8000/api/v1/articles --header
>   "Content-type:application/json"
>
> curl -X POST -d '{"articleContent":"title1"}'
>   http://localhost:8000/api/v1/articles.json

Please to note that the GET returns to me a json like:

> {"id":68,"article_content":"contents contents"}

But my field is `articleContent` in my doctrine mapping file. What am I missing?
Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your header option to:

```
"Content-Type: application/json"
```

Additionally - does this request require any type of authentication? You'd need to pass in an auth cookie if so.

Comment: I did with the Content-Type to no avail. additionnaly when I remove it, I get now an SQL integrity constraint violation error (cannot instert null to column). I then have no authentification,  (obvious since i can even  reach the database layer). My head is acking, thank you very much for your time

Comment: OK, sounds like you need to pass some additional input fields. Are you able to see the structure of the table? That might give you some clues. Also it's typical for a unit test suite to run against a test database, whose schema might not be up to date with the database your curl request is hitting (if indeed there are separate databases).

Comment: Actually, the table is a one-column table with `articleContent` as name of the column (in phpmyadmin). It is also the same name in the doctrine orm file.  I am digging into you comment to check more possible causes (because a documentation is also pointing to some near issue http://welcometothebundle.com/web-api-rest-with-symfony2-the-best-way-the-post-method/#the-name-of-the-form-type) .thanks again

Comment: Does the 'articleContent' column have a 'UNIQUE' constraint set on it? Are you able to insert two rows in phpmyadmin with the same value?